# Como fazer backup do banco de dados para nuvem e como ter os dados sincronizados em vários dispositivos?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, backup, sincronização

Bom pessoal minha dúvida é a seguinte.

Tenho um App que tem um banco de dados local SQLite. Eu quero saber se tem alguma biblioteca, framework, código que faça o seguinte:

Backup desse banco de dados para Nuvem (Servidor próprio ou da Google se ela tiver alguma implementação para isso) e permita ter a mesma base de dados sincronizada entre vários dispositivos.

Vamos ao exemplo: Eu tenho ***2 Smartphones*** e ***1 Tablet***.

1. ***Smartphone 1***
2. ***Smartphone 2***
3. ***Tablet A***

Eu instalei meu app no ***Smartphone 1***. Usei, fiz registros no banco de dados, alterei, deletei.
Eu quero que quando eu desinstalar o App no ***Smartphone 1***, e depois de um tempo, reinstalar, todos os meus dados de quando eu tinha desinstalado sejam importados novamente como se o app nunca tivesse sido desinstalado.
E também, que se eu tiver com o App instalado no ***Smartphone 1*** e quiser instalar no ***Tablet A***, automaticamente todos os dados que estão no ***Smartphone 1*** passem para o App que está instalado no ***Tablet A***.

Agora com o mesmo App instalado em dois dispositivos, caso eu faça alguma mudança em um dispositivo, essa mudança apareça no outro, ou seja, estejam sincronizados.

Como eu faço isso, estou totalmente perdido nessa parte.

Answer (score 10):

Lucas existe sim tecnologia para isso, alias pouco nova no mercado e desconhecida.

Nome dela é: [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/)

> SymmetricDS is open source software for both file and database synchronization with support for multi-master replication, filtered synchronization, and transformation across the network in a heterogeneous environment. It supports multiple subscribers with one direction or bi-directional, asynchronous data replication. It uses web and database technologies to replicate data as a scheduled or near real-time operation. The software was designed to scale for a large number of nodes, work across low-bandwidth connections, and withstand periods of network outage. It works with most operating systems, file systems, and databases, including Oracle, MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server (including Azure), IBM DB2, H2, HSQLDB, Derby, Firebird, Interbase, Informix, Greenplum, SQLite (including Android), Sybase ASE, and Sybase ASA (SQL Anywhere) databases.

Na empresa aqui utilizamos ele, é muito show sua tecnologia.

É uma ferramenta para replicação de dados, ou seja, mantém instâncias atualizadas entre si, e o melhor é possível impor regras, transformation, conflicts resolve e etc para todos os eventos: `UPDATE`, `INSERT` OU `DELETE`;

Imagine que você tem uma **MATRIZ** e necessita que toda vez que um produto seja criado no ERP dela o produto venha **aparecer magicamente** nos ERP das filiais, porém, com algumas regras como alguns campos que não devem ser populados, datas alteradas e etc.

Bem vindo ao SymmetricDS.

Ele é feito em java, então fique tranquilo que tem biblioteca dele para android, onde é montado um `node` no celular que foi instalado o app e sincronizado a base local com uma online. Ai no exemplo que deu que ao instalar necessita que tudo seja populado na base local é só chamar a função `Request Initial Load`

### Algumas funcionalidades

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Fácil configuração e rápida com um painel intuitivo online, configure todos os nodes em uma única interface. Reduza o tempo de resposta para conflitos e configuração sem escrever uma linha de códigos.
- Monitore todoa sua rede de node, possíveis conflitos e erros de uma dashboard. Além de ter acesso ao status de todos os nodes, como por exemplo status do registro que foi alterado, deletado ou criado.
- Lidar com períodos off-line de operação desconectada e fazer uso eficiente das redes de baixa largura de banda. Com durabilidade para garantir a entrega de dados, o sistema automaticamente recupera de falhas.
- Dimensionar para grandes redes de milhares de nós e alavancagem para fora do suporte de caixa para nós de cluster, balanceamento de carga, o carregamento em massa de alto desempenho, ea configuração n-tier.
- Sincronizar os dados em uma empresa heterogênea e ganhar a liberdade de escolher o banco de dados que corresponde ao seu pedido com amplo suporte para plataformas de bancos de dados e sistemas operacionais.
- Sincronizar arquivos e pastas em sistemas operacionais diferentes com o mesmo mecanismo de sincronização de dados que é poderoso e flexível o suficiente para configurar e personalizar.
- Integrar com sistemas externos usando interfaces incluídos de JMS, JDBC, REST, e FTP. Expandir funcionalidade usando pontos extensões e scripts. Incorporar em aplicativos personalizados.
- Manipular dados de alteração durante várias fases de sincronização com transformações internas e scripts personalizados que filtro, subconjunto, traduzir, fundir e enriquecer os dados.
- Reforçar a consistência de sincronização bidirecional, configurando gestão de conflitos com as regras automatizadas, resolvedores personalizados ou manual de resolução a partir de uma tela.

### Algumas imagens

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: eu já tinha dado uma olhada nesse SymmetricDS porém não achei a documentação muito boa e nem exemplos usando Android. Quem faz a lógica de sincronização? Poderia explicar melhor como funciona na parte prática esse SymmetricDS?

Comment: Já expliquei como funciona na prática. Documentação dele é bem abortiva no uso das funções não exemplo de uso do software. Ele fica monitorando seu banco, cada alteração no banco ele faz algo, se você quer sincronizar para outro banco, se você quer transformar o dado e enviar e etc. Se o banco mestre também sofrer alterações ele recebe e sincroniza no banco local. É 100% o que você esta procurando.

Comment: Rapaz, gostei demais do conceito da ferramenta! Vou dar uma olhada agora.

Comment: @TinMegali é sensacional ela. Aqui temos matriz mais de 10 filiais trabalhando sem parar, e com integridade de dados.

Comment: @TinMegali sem dizer que funciona sem internet ;) quer dizer, mesmo se não tiver conexão ele monitora e registra tudo, quando volta ele mantém as bases iguais :)

Comment: @juniorb2ss no caso eu instalaria esse software no meu servidor linux com mysql e também implementaria uma lib no app Android? Aí eu faço minhas funções normais CRUD que ele registra e faz todo o trabalho ou uso funções dele para CRUD?

Comment: No seu servidor você instala ele e configura como mestre. No celular você utiliza a biblioteca e instala um node. O Software é apenas um espião para sua base de dados, ele não entra nada no seu código, ele monitora seu banco. Por triggers ele gerencia todas as alterações, se alguma ocorrer ele replica para o mestre.

Comment: @LucasSantos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuXWCAzIj5g

Comment: @juniorb2ss Quanto custa a versão PRO?

Comment: @LucasSantos 15 mil dólares. Porém é open source. A licença é para o suporte especializado dele e serial para o console. Porém funcionalidade não muda nada, pois é open source.

Comment: @juniorb2ss como você roda ele com a versão community, fiz o dowload, porém não sei como rodo ele, pode me ajudar?

Comment: @Alisson versão community é apenas por commandline, você precisa rodar as querys direto no banco para ir criando as configurações. Recomendo baixar a versão pró, é possível gerar uma licensa por 30 dias, quando pegar o jeito, executa a community

Answer (score 3):

Existem algumas alternativas que podem resolver seu problema, mas a lógica da sincronização ficará por tua conta. Existe um modelo de serviço chamado de **mBaS** (Mobile Backend as a Service - [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Backend_as_a_service)) que faz exatamente isso. Fornece um backend de fácil configuração e geralmente com suporte para vários sistemas.

Existem muitas opções. Uma bastante popular e com uma conta gratuita boa é o [Parse.com](https://parse.com/). Você pode utilizar algo como o [BaasBox](http://www.baasbox.com/), que é openSource e instalar em seu servidor também.

Agora, a lógica e o código da sincronização ficará por tudo conta meu chapa. Não tenho conhecimento de uma library que faça isso por você. Basicamente você precisa manter ps registros do aparelho e os registros da nuvem com as mesmas datas de atualização. Você também poderia cadastrar os *devices* do usuário e utilizar flags no seu servidor para informar aos outros devices quando estes precisarem de atualização, enviando requests apenas quando necessário.

A discussão de **como** fazer isso é filosófica demais. Boa sorte por aí.

**Update**: Segurança e "propriedade" dos objesto no mBasS ( questão levantada nos comentários)

Se a segurança for uma característica fundamental para o sucesso da sua aplicação, talvez os serviços mBasS não sejam a solução ideal. Penso que em função da facilidade de configuração e uso do serviço, algumas decisões foram tomadas (em termos de design) que prejudicam este lado.

Por padrão o Parse mantém o acesso de seus objetos totalmente aberto (o que considero algo bizarro), mas há a possibilidade de utilizar listas **ACL** (Access Control List), que definitivamente não são a arquitetura mais segura do mundo. Através do ACL você define listas de permissões de usuários em cada objeto registrado. Se você precisar de mais um layer de segurança é possível fazer outra autenticação no servidor utilizando a sessão do usuário, por exemplo. Mas é necessário desenvolver isto em *CloudCode* que é um sdk js com algumas funções bastante confusas.

Uma vez os ACL aplicados você consegue fazer uma query somente nos objetos cadastrados para o usuário, por exemplo.

Comment: Caso eu não use nenhuma tecnologia para auxiliar no meu problema, seu comentário me ajudou na parte de cadastrar os devices do usuário e utilizar flags para saber quando atualizar outros dispositivos ou não. Eu havia pensado nisso ontem e agora a ideia foi fortalecida.

Comment: @LucasSantos no symmetric ele da suporte a isso, você cria um campo e toda vez que houver um INSERT você envia o NODE_ID, que significa da onde ta vindo esse dado. E no symmetric você define que só ele pode ver os dados que tiver o NODE_ID dele, então se eu criar um registro no celular A o celular B não irá receber, porém, se na MATRIZ eu editar este registro o celular A irá receber.

Comment: Ele não faz essa parte de se eu criar um registro no Celular A o celular B receber também?

Comment: @LucasSantos Se você quiser que seja assim, sim.

Comment: @Tin Megali esse Parse serve para o que quero? Dei uma olhada nele. É estranho esse tipo de serviço, é como se eu não usasse um banco de dados meu nem local nem remoto, usasse o deles, é isso mesmo? E como é feito o relacionamento?

Comment: @Lucas, você pode utilizar o seu DB local, mas no servidor o banco é deles. Entretanto no SDK eles oferecem uma espécie de cache que salva os arquivos de forma local. Eles não explicam muito bem na documentação como isso funciona, mas eu suponho que o Parse crie um DB local e gerencie através do SDK estas operações. Em função desta falta de controle e possível dependência, na aplicação que desenvolvi no Parse eu utilizei meu DB e fiz as operações no servidor utilizando o REST que eles oferecem. Já aviso que a doc. do REST é péssima e algumas operações são chatas de fazer.

Comment: @LucasSantos acho que o maior problema seria no caso de uma mudança futura. Como se trata de uma ferramenta comercial, certamente não deve ser a coisa mais fácil resgatar todos os seus dados e transferir para um servidor teu por exemplo. Acredito o BaasBox deve lançar a versão 1.0 este ano. Se não me engano está na 0.94. O BaasBox é bem legal. Você pode instalar no seu servidor, até na sua máquina. O único problema é que eu acredito que ainda não chegou a maturidade para uma aplicação comercial. Mas no meu cenário de testes eu não tive nenhum problema. Instalei na amazon e rodou filé.

Comment: @TinMegali Realmente acho que a melhor opção vai ser eu desenvolver minha própria maneira de sincronismo. Valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: Uma última dúvida @TinMegali, esses serviços como o Parse, como eles tratam o relacionamento? Já que no lado deles é um servidor NoSQL tudo a base de JSON. Por exemplo, com esses serviços como Parse e Firebase, eu posso ter um usuário autenticado, e os dados que eu envio serão separados por cada usuário? E como eu faria o relacionamento, exibir somente categorias que estão cadastradas para determinado usuário ou que esteja relacionado com um id de outra coisa. Tipo chave estrangeira.

Comment: @LucasSantos a resposta ficou meio grande. Vou colocar editar meu texto acima. Bom que fica documentado pra todo mundo