# Sincronização MySQL local com remoto

Tags: php, mysql, sincronização, replicação

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer replicação de um Banco de dados MySQL local com o remoto. Uso PhpMyAdmin e não sei se será possível pois não tenho IP fixo pra um encontrar o outro.

Comment: Você pode dar uma olha na minha resposta que dei a um tempo atras, ela também poderá servir para seu problema. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90164/como-fazer-backup-do-banco-de-dados-para-nuvem-e-como-ter-os-dados-sincronizados/90264#90264 Ou acompanhar mais detalhes em meu blog: https://medium.com/@juniorb2s/sincronização-de-bd-bixo-de-sete-cabeças-4d7193dfc1c

Comment: Renan, pode explicar melhor a situação? Você tem um banco local, e quer sincronizar os dados com algum banco em nuvem?

Comment: Sim, é possível e o nome disso se chama replicação master-master. A única particularidade do seu caso é que você teria que usar um no-ip para obter um endereço fixo para ser informado no servidor remoto. Da uma gloogada que você consegue.

Comment: Esse e seu banco de produção ? Se for acho que isso não seria legal

Comment: Caro veja esta resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188495/sincronizar-banco-de-dados-local-e-web/188596#188596

Comment: Só uma observação sobre o No-IP: Não é só criar um no-ip. É preciso também fazer direcionamento da porta TCP 3306 de ENTRADA no seu ADSL (se não usar IP válido e com portas liberadas) para o terminal que hospeda o MySQL. Se sua internet for de provedor de bairro, terá que solicitar DIRECIONAMENTO (não é liberação) de porta para o seu roteador (Ou PC, se for direto).

Answer (score 2):

É possível sim e bem simples de fazer!

1) Como você não possui IP fixo, vá ao site NO-IP  e cadastre um host dns.

2) Baixe o programa deles e deixe executando na máquina onde está o PHPMYADMIN

3) Entre no PHPMYADMIN com seu usuário e senha e vá até as seguintes opções:

CONTAS DE USUÁRIO > Selecione a conta root ou a que você estiver utilizando > EDIT PRIVILEGES > INFORMAÇÃO DE LOGIN > Altere 'HOST NAME' que estará em LOCAL: localhost para QUALQUER MÁQUINA: %

4) Execute e pode acessar o banco de dados externamente em um programa sql(como o navicat), usando o host do no-ip com porta 3306 se não houver alterado, nome do usuario, senha!