# Sincronizar Banco de dados Local e Web

Tags: php, mysql, sincronização, replicação

Tenho um sistema rodando em um servidor web, e também quero colocá-lo pra rodar no servidor local da empresa (intranet), por questões de desempenho...

Percebi que teria um problema com relação à sincronização do banco de dados entre os dois servidores... Pesquisei alguma coisa sobre Replication, mas nada muito esclarecedor...

Gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer essa sincronização instantaneamente - Tudo que for gravado no servidor local, também estar disponível no web, e vice-versa?

Dá pra alguma ferramenta do próprio servidor pra isso?
Preciso nem que saiba de uma função pra quando o cara clicar em um botão, automaticamente transferir os dados do servidor local pro web, e vice-versa.

Alguém poderia me dar um HELP?

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caro, de fato a maneira mais segura de fazer isso é através do Replication. Porém este recurso é para replicação ativa-passiva assíncrona, é mais comumente utilizado para fins de backup e/ou redundância de dados.

Se você precisa de uma replicação ativa-ativa, o único modo seguro que vejo é através do Mysql Cluster: 
https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/ porém esta não é uma solução free e acredito que não seja barata. De qualquer forma a performance de um cluster depende também da qualidade da rede (e no final das contas terá um único ip).

Você poderia explorar outras alternativas (cache local ou remoto ex CloudFront na AWS) ou apenas subir a aplicação na rede local e apontar para o banco remoto.

Também dê uma olhada nesta resposta: [Como fazer backup do banco de dados para nuvem e como ter os dados sincronizados em vários dispositivos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90164/como-fazer-backup-do-banco-de-dados-para-nuvem-e-como-ter-os-dados-sincronizados/90264#90264)

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

abs,